# Plugin directory in IDA?

Tags: ida, python, plugin

According to IDA docs, we can put a Python plugin into $HOME/.idapro/plugins/ directory. But when I copied my Python plugin there & restart IDA, IDA still do not see that.

What can go wrong, and how can I debug this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu/Debian? Whats the name of the plugin? Did you check the `plugins.cfg`?

Comment: It is my own plugin, written in Python. Do I need to modify plugins.cfg to get it loaded? Hmm I dont think so.

Comment: I believe problem may be within your plugin or directory is wrong. Try to get any other python plugins available on hex-rays https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download.shtml  and put it in the same directory. Check if IDA is able to see it after restart. Of so - your plugin is not formatted well. If not - possibly this is a wrong folder.